# Unable to play protected (DRM) content on Chrome

Tags: linux, linux-mint, chrome, adobe-flash

Updated:

First and foremost, please let me know if creating a new question would be 'better' than updating this question. Anyway...
I am currently running Antergos and I am experiencing the same problems. Hal doesn't seem to work and o tried installing an older version to no avail. I am interested in trying to get my 'hands' on a ChromeOS recovery so I can extract its flash player.

To find out if you can play DRM content (from Adobe's help page):

Go to the url in (1) and paste the url in (2) into the "Input the Video URL" bar.

Old:

I upgraded to Linux Mint 17 a couple weeks ago. Prior to that, I was running on LM 16 and had an issue playing protected content on Google Chrome. I fixed that issue after installing hal and disabling Chrome's flash player in favour of Adobe's. But since I'm on LM 17, that problem reared its ugly head again. I recently installed hal and since Chrome no longer gave me the option to disable/enable specific flash plug-ins, I renamed Adobe's to libpepflashplayer and moved it to opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash. Unfortunately, the problem still persists and it's worse now since I know get the notice "Could not load Shockwave Flash."

Linux Mint 17 (64)

Google Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114

Sites attempted to access: Espn3.com, Video.adultswim.com/watch-live

Comment: You might want to mention which site you are trying to access. IIRC the Flash plugin for Linux is an older version which may not support that website ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks and added. You're right that the plugin for Linux is an older version but it was working prior to updating to LM 17 (I forgot what version of Chrome that I was running).

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of Flash plugins on Linux: NPAPI and PPAPI.

Since you copied NPAPI version to place Chrome expects a PPAPI one, it fails to load it.

More important facts are:

1. Google removed support for NPAPI in Chrome;
2. Google also removed DRM support in PPAPI Flash;
3. Chromium is also affected by this.

The only options you have left are:

1. try Firefox (or any other NPAPI-supporting browser) and the dated native NPAPI Flash (you might need to install this: https://launchpad.net/~mjblenner/+archive/ppa-hal)
2. try Firefox (or any other NPAPI-supporting browser) and use Pipelight to install fresh Windows NPAPI Flash
3. install some browser via Wine and use that
4. wait for a new Linux Opera build

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers Karol S gave, note that the PPAPI flash found on ChromeBooks has DRM enabled. You can extract the `libpepflashplayer.so.*` files from a recovery image and substitute them for your existing ones.

Why Google does this, I don't know. My personal solution is Karol S's third option (Pipelight in a NPAPI browser, specifically Seamonkey in my case). But this is an option, too.

[To quote the author of the PPAPI-> NPAPI wrapper](https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin/issues/13#issuecomment-60490990) 'fresh player' (an alternative to pipelight that doesn't work quite as well in my experience but is farless complex to install), this is how you get the plugin library:

> You download [linux_recovery.sh](https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/linux_recovery.sh) from [Chromebook support site](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595). This
>   script has a link to recovery.conf inside, which in turn have links to
>   particular images. Last one I downloaded, was
>   chromeos_5978.98.1_zako_recovery_stable-channel_mp-v2.bin. Its
>   architecture is x86_64, amongst other images you can found x86 (32
>   bit) and ARM.
>
> Downloaded image have multiple partitions, you need partition 3, with
>   root fs. Mount it with "ro" flag. Flash player is in
>   /opt/google/chrome/pepper/.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot I had this question up but I am still experiencing the same problems (will edit my original question in due time). How exactly do I go about downloading the images? I stumbled on that site before but all I could download was a Chrome app.

Comment: @ElDandy there's a URL inside the shellscript that contains a list of the images themselves. The script will pick one from here to download for you: https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/recovery.conf?source=linux_recovery.sh